# Defining member as event handler in F#

Tags: f#

This is probably asked several times but I just can't find an example.

My goal is to define an event handler for an event and the handler should be a member of the class. In other words I don't want to use function since I need to access instance variables and members

The latest variation I've tried:

```
namespace A
    type ValueList<'TValueItem when 'TValueItem :> IValueItem>() =
        inherit System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<'TValueItem>()

        // This is causing error: The value or constructor 'ValueList_CollectionChanged' is not defined
        let collectionChangedHandler = new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ValueList_CollectionChanged)

        // Constructor code
        do base.CollectionChanged.AddHandler(collectionChangedHandler)

        // Handles collection changed events for data items
        member this.ValueList_CollectionChanged(sender : obj, e : System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) =
            // The code I want to run goes here
            ...
```

Or is this maybe a completely wrong approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for the self-identifier syntax:

```
type ValueList<'TValueItem when 'TValueItem :> IValueItem>() as this =
```

The `as this` (or any other identifier in place of `this`) allows to refer to the instance being constructed from the constructor.

You could then change your other lines to use the identifier:

```
let collectionChangedHandler = new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(this.ValueList_CollectionChanged)

do this.CollectionChanged.AddHandler(collectionChangedHandler)
```

For this to be valid as-is, the `ValueList_CollectionChanged` method also needs to be in curried form:

```
member this.ValueList_CollectionChanged (sender : obj) (e : System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) =
```

As an alternative to using curried arguments, you can use a lambda to transform the arguments where the handler is instantiated, e.g. `.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(fun sender e -> this.(...)`.